# How to proof that a equation without operators has only one solution?

Tags: puzzle, programming

I need help with a logical thing.
Suppose I have an equation with multiple numbers (which are all single digits and 1-9).

For example: $4 * 4 - 3 = 13.$  How can I proof, that this equation has only one solution when the operators are unknown?

I want to generate puzzles in the form `4 ◦ 7 ◦ 1 ◦ 9 ◦ 8 ◦ 1 ◦ 8 ◦ 2 ◦ 2 = 134` where each `◦` represents a unknown operator. But each puzzle must have a definite solution, meaning it can only be solved in one way.

For example: $3\ ?\ 4\ ?\ 3 = 15$

Has the solutions: $3 * 4 + 3 = 15$ and $3 + 4 * 3 = 15$ (Which is not something I want to have.)

Maybe the reverse polish notation helps? When generating using trees to compare it somehow? My current solution is to brute-force all possible solutions and check if the outcome has multiple ways of solving.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming but this is a math forum. Use `3\cdot 4` to get $3\cdot 4$ and `3\times 4` to get $3 \times 4$ when using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the math (which you should when posting here)

Comment: What operators are you considering? I guess $+, -, \times$, may be also $\div$? Any others?

Comment: Only those 4, yeah! Notation is from left to right and multiplication and devision before minus and plus

Comment: You have uncovered one rule: if you have adjacent numbers $a\ \square\ b\ \square\ a$ anywhere in your puzzle, where the internal operations have at least as high a precedence as the those surrounding, then the desired operations between them cannot be a multiplication and an addition. But in general, I think you will have to check by brute force that there is only one solution.